# Events nearby in a city for android application

Tags: android, events, google-maps, android-layout

Android application should show `Events` happening in city as per `day/month/year` anywhere in the world.
 Is there any `API` to use in android application ?
Few application providing events such as  [Poynt](http://www.poynt.com/) . 
 I'm not getting how they provide but if any one know this issue please suggest about it .

Comment: The best you can get from FACEBOOK EVENTS API....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better that i wont purchase any `API`for events and its huge collection so as a begginner , i would try to go on writing few events in `XML` on my server and i would parse with it in android . Display it on android `xml` file with set text view .

On my server i should collect few events as per `event name , date , venue and description`.
Later i would display it in my android application events . when user click on event button in my application they would get my details as entered.

Comment: could you do that? How did you create server?

Answer (score 6):

You will most likely have to use multiple API's somewhat split up in categories as follows, I doubt any open database with any decent API exists that contains anything close to "everywhere" or "every" event in the world...so you'd have to pick your battle, what do you really want to offer:

MUSIC

- Last.fm - http://www.last.fm/api
- Songkick - http://www.songkick.com/developer
- Jambase - http://developer.jambase.com/
- Gruvr - http://gruvr.com/developers/

SOCIAL

- Meetup - http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/
- Plancast - http://plancast.com/api
- Facebook Events - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

I have not been able to find tried and true all inclusive and open database which also offers an API except for the following:

- Eventful - http://api.eventful.com/

and you may generally want to browse something like: the [WebAPI Finder](http://www.webapifinder.com/api/filter?category=events)

That's a few to get you started. I really think you need to start small and grow large. How do you want to start or be seen as (audience, event type, etc). It will be easier to start off in specific geographic locations too. Start small and grow larger.

Answer (score 2):

You can use every API you want from the internet.
I think a very good one to start with is the API from facebook. More specific the Event part of the `Facebook API`, have a look at this : [Facebook Event API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/)